# What should i pass into the onclick function in checkbox

Tags: javascript

The problem comes when passing the values of checkbox to the onclick function when i pass in "this" into the onclick function in order to get the value of the checkbox it gives an error so i want the support on what should i pass and how to get the value of checkbox.

this is the code where i pass the values(HTML)

```
<label>Step 4: Add delux wrapping:</label>
<input type="checkbox" name="delux" value="giftDeluxe" onclick="view(this);">
```

the javascript code where I get the value of checkbox into a variable

````
function view(frm){
var extra = frm.delux.value;

}```

the expected output should be `extra = the value of the checkbox("giftDeluxe")`
the error that i get is: 

    Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of undefined
        at view (practiseExam.html:36)
        at HTMLInputElement.onclick (practiseExam.html:87)
````

Comment: you need to format your code in the question properly, the value could be in delux.innerText

Comment: Where is the form element? "frm" doesn't have a reference in the code you provided. There is not an element in your HTML either.

Comment: sorry the code was not added properly

Comment: `var extra = document.querySelector('[name="delux"]').value`

Comment: Thanks. Can i know the reason why i can't use this method to get the value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are passing the checkbox as the sender to the function, you can just call `this.value` to get the value for the checkbox that was clicked.

In my example, "this" is passed to a variable called "sender." I call `sender.value` to get the value from the checkbox.

```
<label>Step 4: Add delux wrapping:</label>
<input type="checkbox" name="delux" value="giftDeluxe" onclick="view(this);">


<script type="text/javascript">

   function view(sender) {
      var extra = sender.value;
      console.log('extra -> ' + extra);
   }

</script>
```

Comment: You're welcome. If you wouldn't mind, please mark this post as the answer. Happy coding!